# ReferenceError: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables. Invalid variable access: React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to use React.useEffect in jest.mock() but get the following error: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables. Invalid variable access: React.

My test file is as follows:

```
jest.mock('@chegg-commerce/coupon', () => ({
  Coupon: ({
    mockAddCoupon,
    mockRemoveCoupon,
  }: {
    mockAddCoupon: Function;
    mockRemoveCoupon: Function;
  }) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      // referenceError here
      mockAddCoupon({
        status: 'ERROR',
        command: 'ADD_COUPON',
        payload: {},
      });
      mockRemoveCoupon({
        status: 'ERROR',
        command: 'REMOVE_COUPON',
        payload: {},
      });
    }, [mockAddCoupon, mockRemoveCoupon]);
    return <div>MockComponent</div>;
  },
}));

jest.mock('../helper');
```

How I can resolve this error?